# Is there a way to use the fmt.Scan() function with a message in one line?

Tags: go

Is there is a way to get an input from the user with a message in one line, like in python where you would do `name = input("Name: ")` instead of doing:

```
var name string
fmt.Println("Name: ")
fmt.Scan(&name)
```